# Android: Positioning of SQL lite rawQuery-cursor takes almost 2 seconds

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I am having problem with `sqllite`. I perform a query on my database and it is surprisingly slow (I debug on a real device).
I added `Trace` commands to SystemTrace what takes so much time. It turned out the call of `rawQuery.moveToFirst()` is the bottleneck here. According to the system performance trace, the call of it alone takes a bit more than 1,5 seconds(!)

```
Cursor rawQuery = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null); // takes 0.5 milliseconds
rawQuery.moveToFirst();
do {
            // assing values
} while (rawQuery.moveToNext());
rawQuery.close();
```

This is extremely slow. Anyone any suggestions how to speed this up?

UPDATE:
Here the sql's for my two tables on which I perform my query. It seems the inner join operation is what demands so much time:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (_id int(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  text_1 VARCHAR(20), text_2 VARCHAR(40));

CREATE TABLE translation (_id int(7), language VARCHAR(10), meaning VARCHAR(100), FOREIGN KEY (_id) REFERENCES table_1(_id));
CREATE INDEX lang_match ON translation (language);


myDataBase.rawQuery("Select a._id, a.text_1, a.text_2, b.meaning from table_1 a inner join translation b ON a._id=b._id AND b.language='eng' WHERE text_1 like ?", new String[] { s + "%" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimize the query and move the database operations off the main UI thread.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not run it. Moving the cursor actually runs the compiled SQL program, and in case of Android SQLite, there's a `CursorWindow` buffer that gets filled with cursor data. If the query involves e.g. a lot of I/O operations, it takes a long time to fill the cursor window.

Comment: I altered my sql a bit. I am currently performing a join operation to get an additional field. If I do not do the join, the speed is acceptable. As soon as I perform a join by using the primary key of 2 tables, it becomes extremely slow. Is it possible to precompile the sql statement for selects? Would that help?

Comment: @user1091534 It is impossible to answer such questions without the database schema and the actual query.